# jquery-addresspicker how to make the marker move

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have downloaded [this demo](http://xilinus.com/jquery-addresspicker/demos/index.html)

How can I make the marker move to the position that I click in the map without the need to drag the marker?

Here is the [original source code](https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker)

Here is the code:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

    $.widget( "ui.addresspicker", {
        options: {
            appendAddressString: "",
            draggableMarker: true,
            regionBias: null,
            componentsFilter:'',
            updateCallback: null,
            reverseGeocode: false,
            autocomplete: 'default',
            mapOptions: {
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(46, 2),
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            },
            elements: {
                map: false,
                lat: false,
                lng: false,
                street_number: false,
                route: false,
                locality: false,
                administrative_area_level_2: false,
                administrative_area_level_1: false,
                country: false,
                postal_code: false,
                type: false
            },
            autocomplete: '' // could be autocomplete: "bootstrap" to use bootstrap typeahead autocomplete instead of jQueryUI
        },

        marker: function() {
            return this.gmarker;
        },

        map: function() {
            return this.gmap;
        },

        updatePosition: function() {
            this._updatePosition(this.gmarker.getPosition());
        },

        reloadPosition: function() {
            this.gmarker.setVisible(true);
            this.gmarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat.val, this.lng.val));
            this.gmap.setCenter(this.gmarker.getPosition());
        },

        selected: function() {
            return this.selectedResult;
        },
        _mapped: {},
        _create: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.geocoder = {
                geocode: function(options, callback) {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" + jQuery.param(options) + '&sensor=false',
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function(data) {
                            callback(data.results, data.status);
                        }
                    });
                }
                //new google.maps.Geocoder();
            };

            if (this.options.autocomplete === 'bootstrap') {
                this.element.typeahead({
                    source: function(query, process) {
                        self._mapped = {};
                        var response = function(results) {
                            var labels = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                self._mapped[results[i].label] = results[i];
                                labels.push(results[i].label);
                            };
                            process(labels);
                        }
                        var request = {term: query};
                        self._geocode(request, response);
                    },
                    updater: function(item) {
                        var ui = {item: self._mapped[item]}
                        self._focusAddress(null, ui);
                        self._selectAddress(null, ui);
                        return item;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                this.element.autocomplete($.extend({
                    source: $.proxy(this._geocode, this),
                    focus:  $.proxy(this._focusAddress, this),
                    select: $.proxy(this._selectAddress, this)
                }), this.options.autocomplete);
            }

            this.lat      = $(this.options.elements.lat);
            this.lng      = $(this.options.elements.lng);
            this.street_number = $(this.options.elements.street_number);
            this.route = $(this.options.elements.route);
            this.locality = $(this.options.elements.locality);
            this.administrative_area_level_2 = $(this.options.elements.administrative_area_level_2);
            this.administrative_area_level_1 = $(this.options.elements.administrative_area_level_1);
            this.country  = $(this.options.elements.country);
            this.postal_code = $(this.options.elements.postal_code);
            this.type     = $(this.options.elements.type);
            if (this.options.elements.map) {
                this.mapElement = $(this.options.elements.map);
                this._initMap();
            }
        },

        _initMap: function() {
            if (this.lat && this.lat.val()) {
                this.options.mapOptions.center = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat.val(), this.lng.val());
            }

            this.gmap = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement[0], this.options.mapOptions);
            this.gmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: this.options.mapOptions.center,
                map:this.gmap,
                draggable: this.options.draggableMarker
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(this.gmarker, 'dragend', $.proxy(this._markerMoved, this));
            this.gmarker.setVisible(false);
        },    

        _updatePosition: function(location) {
            if (this.lat) {
                this.lat.val(location.lat());
            }
            if (this.lng) {
                this.lng.val(location.lng());
            }
        },

        _addressParts: {
            street_number: null,
            route: null,
            locality: null,
            administrative_area_level_2: null,
            administrative_area_level_1: null,
            country: null,
            postal_code:null,
            type: null
        },

        _updateAddressParts: function(geocodeResult){
            parsedResult = this._parseGeocodeResult(geocodeResult);
            for (addressPart in this._addressParts){
                if (this[addressPart]){
                    this[addressPart].val(parsedResult[addressPart]);
                }
            }
        },

        _updateAddressPartsViaReverseGeocode: function(location){
            this.geocoder.geocode({
                'latlng': location.lat() + "," + location.lng()
            },
            $.proxy(function(results, status){
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)

                this._updateAddressParts(results[0]);
                this.element.val(results[0].formatted_address);
                this.selectedResult = results[0];

                if (this.options.updateCallback) {
                    this.options.updateCallback(this.selectedResult, this._parseGeocodeResult(this.selectedResult));
                }
            }, this));
        },

        _parseGeocodeResult: function(geocodeResult){
            var parsed = {
                lat: geocodeResult.geometry.location.lat,
                lng: geocodeResult.geometry.location.lng
            };

            for (var addressPart in this._addressParts){
                parsed[addressPart] = this._findInfo(geocodeResult, addressPart);
            }

            parsed.type = geocodeResult.types[0];

            return parsed;
        },

        _markerMoved: function() {
            this._updatePosition(this.gmarker.getPosition());

            if (this.options.reverseGeocode){
                this._updateAddressPartsViaReverseGeocode(this.gmarker.getPosition());
            }
        },

        // Autocomplete source method: fill its suggests with google geocoder results
        _geocode: function(request, response) {
            var address = request.term, self = this;
            this.geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address + this.options.appendAddressString,
                'region': this.options.regionBias,
                'components': this.options.componentsFilter
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        result = results[i]
                        g = result.geometry
                        g.location = new google.maps.LatLng(g.location.lat, g.location.lng);
                        g.viewport = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                            new google.maps.LatLng(g.viewport.southwest.lat, g.viewport.southwest.lng),
                            new google.maps.LatLng(g.viewport.northeast.lat, g.viewport.northeast.lng)
                        )
                        result.label =  results[i].formatted_address;
                    };
                }
                response(results);
            })
        },

        _findInfo: function(result, type) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.address_components.length; i++) {
                var component = result.address_components[i];
                if (component.types.indexOf(type) !=-1) {
                    return component.long_name;
                }
            }
            return false;
        },

        _focusAddress: function(event, ui) {
            var address = ui.item;
            if (!address) {
                return;
            }
            if (this.gmarker) {
                this.gmarker.setPosition(address.geometry.location);
                this.gmarker.setVisible(true);
                this.gmap.fitBounds(address.geometry.viewport);
            }
            this._updatePosition(address.geometry.location);
            this._updateAddressParts(address);
        },

        _selectAddress: function(event, ui) {
            this.selectedResult = ui.item;
            if (this.options.updateCallback) {
                this.options.updateCallback(this.selectedResult, this._parseGeocodeResult(this.selectedResult));
            }
        }
    });

    $.extend( $.ui.addresspicker, {
        version: "@VERSION"
    });

    // make IE think it doesn't suck
    if(!Array.indexOf){
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
            for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
                if(this[i]==obj){
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this issue](https://github.com/sgruhier/jquery-addresspicker/issues/30). It works for me.

Comment: It's link only answer, include essential part of the original source because if link becomes dead, your answer will become dead too!